# SQL: Get Sum of Column AND Last Entry

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I am joining together:

```
    SELECT 
        type, 
        name,
        SUM(value) as total_value,
        target,
        target_month,
        operator,
        SUM(value_1) as total_value1,
        AVG(average_of_total) as average
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            stats.`type`, stat_type.`target`, stat_type.`target_month`, stat_type.`operator`, stats.`monthly`, stats.`value`, stats.`value_1`, stats.`created_at`, `name`, stats.`average_of_total`   
        FROM 
            tefl_stats_customer as stats 
        JOIN 
          tefl_stats_customer_type as stat_type 
        ON 
          stats.`type` = stat_type.`id`) AS all_data
    WHERE
        created_at BETWEEN '20147-05-09 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-10 23:00:00' AND monthly = 0
    GROUP BY `type`
```

at the moment this is returning:

```
    | type | Name       | total_value     | target     | target_month     | operator     | total_value1      | average      |
    |   12 | English    | 3,378           | 400        | 8000             | <=           | 0                 | 0            |
    |    9 | Chinese    | 314             | 24         | 0                | =            | 426               | 2.03698      |
    |    1 | Japanese   | 374             | 5          | 0                | <            | 78                | 6.5          |
```

At the moment, as you can see I am getting the **SUM()** of **'value'** as **total_value**.

Value is found in the table: **tefl_stats_customer**. This table has thousand of rows.

How can I get the last row in the above query and to have that outputted as **last_entry**?

Comment: `How can I get the last row in the above query and to have that outputted as last_entry` ... what does this mean?  Can you show us your expected output?  By the way, your current query has a problem because you are grouping by the `type` but selecting non aggregate columns.

Comment: The values you get in for expressions `name`, `target`, `target_month` and `operator` are [*indeterminate*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). They might be picked from different rows. `GROUP BY` does not return rows from the table, it **generates new rows** using groups of rows having the same values in the columns from the `GROUP BY` clause. Your query is not valid SQL (because of the aforementioned expressions in the `SELECT` clause) and it is accepted only by MySQL. Other RDBMSes reject it.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query